# Automatically re-check a checkbox when I decheck another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

As a student, I am trying to learn some JQuery tricks.
Here my HTML

```
<div id="EngineGroup" class="OptionGroupStyle">
    <div id="GS300"><input id="GS300Check" name="GS300Check" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"/>V6 250ch</div>
    <div id="GS300Price">53.000 €</div>
    <div id="GS430"><input id="GS430Check" name="GS430Check" type="checkbox"/>V8 283ch</div>
    <div id="GS430Price">58.000 €</div>
    <div id="GS450H"><input id="GS450HCheck" name="GS450HCheck" type="checkbox"/>V8 Hybride 345ch</div>
    <div id="GS450HPrice">63.000 €</div>
</div>
```

GS300 is the default option.

- When "GS430Check" is checked -> GS300 and GS450H are unchecked
- When "GS450HCheck" is checked -> GS300 and GS430 are unchecked

It's ok for that with

```
$("#GS430Check").click(function() {
        $("input[name=GS300Check]").attr("checked",false);
        $("input[name=GS450HCheck]").attr("checked",false);
});
```

same for GS450H

But how can I can automatically re-check GS300 by default when I uncheck/unselect GS430 or GS450H when they are already checked ?
I couldn't find something like ondeCheck/ondeSelect in JQuery, did I miss something or am I a real noob who can't understand something really simple ?

Edit :

```
$("#EngineGroup input").click(function() {
    if (!$("#EngineGroup input:checked").length) {
        $("#EngineGroup input:first").attr("checked", true);
    }
});
```

is working great :)

Comment: That's some strange functionality. Somehow a radio button sounds more appropriate. Anyway, you should add a `click` or `onchange` event handler to all 3 checkboxes, and inside it, check if all 3 checkboxes are unchecked, then recheck the default one.

Comment: Yea, I agree with Mark. Btw, it should be "uncheck" instead of 'decheck" :)

Comment: Yes, I agree with you about radio button (but you know.. teachers..) and I can't change the HTML code.
So now I am trying something like that but I doesn't work (I can even check a checkbox) : 

$('#EngineGroup input[type=checkbox]').change( function() {
  if($("input[name=GS430Check]").attr("checked",false) && $("input[name=GS450HCheck]").attr("checked",false) && $("input[name=GS460Check]").attr("checked",false)){
            $("input[name=GS300Check]").attr("checked",true);
  }
});

Did I miss something ? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the HTML, then I'd suggest that it might be easier to simply save the current state of a checkbox on a click, then uncheck all the boxes and flip the state of the clicked checkbox to the opposite of it's previous state.  If there are still none checked after this, you should simply check the default checkbox.  This way you could do it all in a single handler instead of having a handler per checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using the [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method in jQuery to see if something is checked:

```
if ($('#GS430Check').is(':checked')) {
  // do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget jQuery's `attr()` and `is()` for getting and setting the checkedness of a checkbox. They are hugely overcomplicated and inefficient for this task. Instead, use the much simpler boolean `checked` property of the checkbox element:

```
if ( $('#GS430Check')[0].checked ) {
    $('#GS300Check')[0].checked = true;
}
```